# Maven. Build only module that have deploy profile

Tags: maven

Context:

I have a rather large system with several maven module formed in a hierarchy. When I need to develop I can go to the root and build using a specific profile -Pdeploy

The problem with this is that, my entire project is built (which takes a while) when I only in truth need to build a dozen lightweight modules that just deploy.

How should I got into improving the team's efficiency when deploying?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Idea**: You may not skip building modules but you may skip some of your plugin executions contained.

Usually your repository will already have build module artifacts present, so the overall speed should already be better once a previous build have been run and module artifacts can be pulled from there.

The idea is that you add a profile setting that defines skip-properties according to what you may want to omit when doing a deploy profile build only.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault />
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skip.documentation>false</skip.documentation>
        <skip.sign>false</skip.sign>
        <skip.sources>false</skip.sources>
        <skip.checks>false</skip.checks>
        <skip.reports>false</skip.reports>
        <skip.installer>false</skip.installer>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>deploy</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.documentation>true</skip.documentation>
        <skip.sign>true</skip.sign>
        <skip.sources>true</skip.sources>
        <skip.checks>true</skip.checks>
        <skip.reports>true</skip.reports>
        <skip.installer>true</skip.installer>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Your pom than might contain

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${version.maven-checkstyle-plugin}</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>${skip.checks}</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This method can be applied on a project pom level (pluginDependencies) or overridden in each module.